# Using monthcalendar control, when i select a day and use that as a filter for my SQL it does not work as expected

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime, monthcalendar

I am trying to use the selectionstart and selectionend attributes from monthcalendar to filter between two login dates in a table. When I chose one single day, this does not work correctly. If i chose the day before and the day after the day in question then it will. The time values in my DB are like this:

```
2/23/2010 11:17:01 AM
```

Both login and logout are of that type. I have a feeling that when I use selectionstart and selection end, I just get the mm/dd/yyyy and what is in the DB is that and a time.

Here is my code:

```
Dim cn As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim str As String
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader

    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()

    Try
        cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=G:\Sean\BMSBonder3_0.mdb;")
        cn.Open()
        str = "Select BonderIdentifier, UserName, Login, Logout From [Session] Where Login >= ? AND Logout <= ? AND BonderIdentifier = ?"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Start", MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("End", MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BID", ListBox1.SelectedItem)

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read()
            If dr.Item(0).ToString <> "" Then
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr.Item(0), dr.Item(1), dr.Item(2), dr.Item(3))

            End If
        End While

        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: tried with `Login between ? AND ?` ?

Comment: Sorry that part of the code was wrong. See above I changed it.

Comment: What type are your login and logout values in DB?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, a really late reply, but I'm doing it because maybe someone looking for this will come across this page.

I think instead of using:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Start", MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("End", MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd)
```

You should use

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Start", MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("End", MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End)
```

Comment: Care to comment why adding the `SelectionRange` will work it out?

Comment: That is exactly the same only longer code. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.selectionstart(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

If you have a look at the problem from a distance, you will realize you cannot have a login after your logout date, same with the logout, you cannot have a logout before your login date. This means that you will have to specify boundaries for your login and logout in your query. Your query should then look like this:

```
Select BonderIdentifier, UserName, Login, Logout From [Session] Where Login >= ? AND login <= ? AND logout >= ? AND Logout <= ? AND BonderIdentifier = ?
```

Where the parameters will be:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Start1", MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Start2", MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("End1", MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("End2", MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End)
```

Comment: I think this will result in even less results. The solution is adding a day to the End value. In that way it will include all times on the previous day.